# custom view for datavisualization

Tags: android

in my Android App I show the user some messages. Therfore I have Linearlayouts which contain a textview. Whenever the App receives a new message I add a LinearLayout to my page, set the LinearLayout's background to a custom one and then add the TextView to it in code. What I want to do is to create a custom View, which is basically the LinearLayout with a custom background and the textview in it. And/or a View which displays all the messages by itself.

What I want to achieve is that I only have to add one view to my XML-Layoutfile. In my code I then simply add all the messages to a property of the view and those messages are displayed automatically.

I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sound's that you are looking for listview or recyclerview.

Comment: Do you have a question as well?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like Andre Classen said a RecyclerView is maybe the best way for your. You can create custom layouts for different Cards, Rows, and display them.

Here you find more about the [Recycler View](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) with Official Tutorial.